# Proving a spectrum is a subset of another

Tags: complex-analysis, banach-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be Banach Algebras and $T: A \rightarrow B$ be a homomorphism.

Using the inclusion $T(A^{-1}) \subseteq B^{-1}$, prove $\sigma(T(a), B) \subseteq \sigma(a,A)$ for all $a \in A$.

---

I think I understand why this is true and this was my idea for a proof but it feels kind of wrong, especially using cardinality:

For this proof let $|X|$ denote the size of the set $X$.

$T(A)^{-1} \subseteq B^{-1}$

therefore $|A^{-1}| \leq |B^{-1}|.$

therefore $|\sigma(a,A)| \geq |\sigma(T(a))|$

and additionally, $T(A^{-1}) \subseteq B^{-1} \Rightarrow \sigma(a,A) \cap \sigma(T(a),B) \subseteq
\sigma(a,A)$

and thus $\sigma(T(a), B) \subseteq \sigma(a,A)$ for all $a \in A$

Comment: \begin{align}
\lambda\in \sigma\big(T(a),B\big)&\implies T(a-\lambda)=T(a)-\lambda\not\in B^{-1}\\
&\implies T(a-\lambda)\not\in T\big(A^{-1}\big)\ \ \big(\text{ because }\ T\big(A^{-1}\big)\subseteq B^{-1}\big)\\
&\implies a-\lambda\not\in A^{-1}\\
&\implies \lambda\in\sigma\big(a,A\big)
\end{align}

Comment: thanks that's a nice concise solution!